# Capture and Reuse Cookies with Requests

Tags: python, cookies, request, session-cookies, python-requests

I've seen posts on how to use the Requests library in Python to send a cookie, but haven't been able to find anything on sending multiple. I'm trying to capture the entire RequestsCookieJar and use it as the cookies for future Posts. Here is what I'm currently working with:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> content = s.get('https://admin.url.com/login.html', verify=False)
>>> print s.cookies
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie _hauavc_4699a329=b27e38d for .url.com/>, <Cookie ut=e for .url.com/>, <Cookie auth_token=5227121307 for admin.url.com/>, <Cookie cwd-extranet=1 for admin.url.com/>, <Cookie slan=en for admin.url.com/>]>
```

I need to pass both the auth_token cookie and _hauavc* cookie any time I use my script later on. I've tried:

```
c = {'auth_token': '5227121307', '_hauavc_4699a329': 'b27e38d'}
```

and sending this in the post with the `cookies=c` option. I've also tried setting:

```
c = s.cookies
```

and sending it the same way. Both tries do not raise any exceptions, but when I go to run the script later, it doesn't appear to acknowledge the cookies. I currently have the process working with Selenium, but have yet to be able to get it to with with Requests. If it helps, here are the cookies I captured with Selenium and use a loop with the `driver.add_cookie()` functions:

```
c = [{u'domain': u'.url.com', u'name': u'_hauavc_64331bfa', u'value': u'61087df', u'expiry': 1424371385, u'path': u'/', u'secure': True},
{u'domain': u'admin.url.com', u'name': u'auth_token', u'value': u'1138335497', u'expiry': 1424371384, u'path': u'/', u'secure': False}]
```

EDIT: 
Including the full code as requested:

```
import requests
c = {
    '_hauavc_64331bfa': '61087df',
    'auth_token': '1020504164',
}
s = requests.Session()
content = s.get(
    'https://admin.url.com/login.html',
    verify=False,
    cookies=c
)
soup = Bs(content.text)
session_id = soup.find('input', {'id': 'ses'}).get('value')
payload = {
    'loginname': username,
    'password': password,
    'ses': session_id,
    'login': 'Login',
    'lang': 'en'
}
content = s.post(
    'https://admin.url.com/login.html',
    data=payload,
    verify=False,
    cookies=c
)
```

EDIT2: And here is the console history of me trying to capture and reuse the cookies:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> c = s.get('https://admin.url.com/login.html', verify=False)
>>> soup = Bs(content.text)
>>> session_id = soup.find('input', {'id': 'ses'}).get('value')
>>> payload = {
...     'loginname': username,
...     'password': password,
...     'ses': session_id,
...     'login': 'Login',
...     'lang': 'en'
... }
>>> content = s.post(
...     'https://admin.url.com/login.html',
...     data=payload,
...     verify=False
... )
>>> payload = {'phone_id': '2c7f576cde7d1c43234f867d679a961f'}
>>> content = s.post('https://admin.url.com/new_location/verify.html?h_id=777143&ses=%s' % session_id, verify=False, data=payload)>>> payload = {'ask_pin': '674802'}
>>> content = s.post('https://admin.url.com/new_location/confirm.html?h_id=777143&ses=%s' % session_id, verify=False, data=payload)
>>> captured_cookies = s.cookies
>>> s.close()
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> content = s.get(
...     'https://admin.booking.com/hotel/hoteladmin/login.html', 
...     verify=False, 
...     cookies=captured_cookies
... )
>>> soup = Bs(content.text)
>>> session_id = soup.find('input', {'id': 'ses'}).get('value')
>>> payload = {
...     'loginname': username,
...     'password': password,
...     'ses': session_id,
...     'login': 'Login',
...     'lang': 'en'
... }
>>> content = s.post(
...     'https://admin.url.com/login.html',
...     data=payload,
...     verify=False,
...     cookies=captured_cookies
... )
>>> print s.cookies
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
```

Comment: Please show the actual code that captures the cookies and sends them in the next request. There's a good chance that the problem is in that code, but without seeing that code there's no way anyone can debug it.

Comment: @abarnert actually, I'm sorry I misread what you said. I included the code of me trying to pass them manually. When I tried to capture them manually, it was just using the console. I'll try to copy and paste what I tried and add it as well.