# How to proper post auth and login, cant seem to get it to work

Tags: json, python-3.x, request, scrapy

I am trying to currently login and post my credentials + token, but for some reason, I keep getting the error: "ValueError: No  element found in "

Been looking on StackOverflow, can't seem to get it to work.

```
import scrapy
import re
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class autologinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'autologin'
    start_urls = ['https://admin.booking.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "op_token")]').re(r'"op_token":"(.*?)"')[0]
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={
            "login_name": "loginname",
            "password": "password",
            "op_token": token
        },  callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
```

I expect to successfully login, but it seems to execute a javascript in order to log in. Hence I am stuck and not able to properly carry on with my code.

Comment: when I go in interactively, the login name is on the first page and no password prompt comes up until an existing login name is given. The payload should not have a password.

Comment: after entering a username, it will ask for a password. Similar case as Gmail for example, but the code might not be.

Comment: yeah, I see that (for example admin). But the first payload sent to https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name has no password, and the second (sent to https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/password) has a payload with a client_id among other things. I would think you'd want to emulate what you see in Network activity in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example? As I am unsure what you mean.

Comment: What I am suggesting is this. Using choose options for developer tools. Click on the network tab and then headers. Input your url. You should see a name admin.booking.com. Then one with authorize redirect and a client_id built into that url. Then another name with sign-in?opToken=. Enter your login name. Look at the item sent called login_name. click on headers to see what the request payload should look like (scroll to the bottom). Then do the same for password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already did that(following network procedure), but I am not sure how to start doing that, I followed documentation guidelines to get this code running and not sure if scrappy supports this. Still a novice coder, so wouldn't know how to emulate that proces.

Comment: So I am not familiar with scrapy. Maybe a reader is. https://medium.com/@geneng/web-crawling-made-easy-with-scrapy-and-rest-api-ed993e84abd3 seems to be sketching how to use scrapy with rest. But I think a first step is to one form request without password in the form data and then another form request with payload you see in the password entry on Chrome.

Comment: Looks like your callback will not be to start scraping, but to the password entry. Its callback will be to start scraping.

Comment: Even if I emulate that process, still receive a "ValueError: No element found in " hmm, tried the login first.

Comment: So I think you need to check which line that is coming from. Does token contain what you think? IS it failing when you say token= or on the form_request?

Comment: Tried using ' account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name' as starturl, give me no error but no value at all. Yes the token can be seen, when u view source, it automatically assigns you one.

Comment: Hmm. Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022939/error-raise-valueerrorno-element-found-in-s-response-occur-when-try-to-l?

Answer (score 0):

The form does not appear to be available for scrapy. I managed to make it work by using normal Requests and hardcoding the login-urls.
If you change the login, password and client_id in the below it should work.

```
import scrapy
import json


class autologinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'autologin'
    start_urls = ['https://admin.booking.com']
    custom_settings = {'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False}

    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36"
    login_name = ""
    password = ""

    def start_requests(self):
        headers = {'User-Agent': self.user_agent}
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,
                                 callback=self.parse,
                                 headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        url = "https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name"
        headers = {
            'Referer': 'https://account.booking.com/',
            'Origin': 'https://account.booking.com',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }

        token = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "op_token")]').re(
            r'"op_token":"(.*?)"')[0]

        client_id = response.xpath('//script[contains(., "client_id")]').re(
            r'"client_id":"(.*?)"')[0]

        return scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            method='POST',
            headers=headers,
            body=json.dumps({
                "login_name": self.login_name,
                "op_token": token
            }),
            meta={'token': token,
                  'client_id': client_id},
            callback=self.parse_pw)

    def parse_pw(self, response):
        url = "https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/password"
        headers = {
            'Origin': 'https://account.booking.com',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
            'User-Agent': self.user_agent,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        }
        token = response.meta['token']
        client_id = response.meta['client_id']

        data = {"login_name": self.login_name,
                "password": self.password,
                "client_id": client_id,
                "state": "",
                "scope": "",
                "code_challenge": "",
                "code_challenge_method": "",
                "op_token": token
                }

        return scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            method='POST',
            headers=headers,
            body=json.dumps(data),
            callback=self.redirect)

    def redirect(self, response):
        redirect_uri = json.loads(response.body)['redirect_uri']
        yield scrapy.Request(redirect_uri,
                             callback=self.start_scraping)

    def start_scraping(self, response):
        return
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried the following and received this:  

The 1e error:
I received: ' <400 HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed '

I tried solving this by using: handle_httpstatus_list = [400]


2e error:
Afterwards, I am getting the current error: line 70, in redirect
    redirect_uri = json.loads(response.body)['redirect_uri']
KeyError: 'redirect_uri'

Comment: Did tou change the login name (2 places), password and client id?

Comment: I added the answer to overwrite the start_requests so it makes sure you add a user-agent to the first request. You don't need to set handle_httpstatus_list = [400], we should rather figure out why you get a 400 status code

Comment: Yea, we are now back at the following: ` '2019-07-19 15:41:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name/> (referer: https://account.booking.com)
2019-07-19 15:41:33 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed`

Comment: Strange, works fine for me: `2019-07-19 22:38:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name> (referer: https://account.booking.com/)`. Maybe your IP is blocked?

Comment: Fascinating, I just checked. When I don't enter any credentials, I get your response. Whenever I fill it all in, I get the 400 not handles issue.

Comment: Seems that if you give invalid credentials you can get a 400 response as well. Sure you're using good credentials?

Comment: perhaps this method might work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135753/capture-and-reuse-cookies-with-requests although I wouldn't know how to implement that into my code.

Comment: I don't think handling the cookies manually will help. Make sure you have COOKIES_ENABLED set to True in settings (default value). You can set COOKIES_DEBUG to True to see the cookies you send & receive to investigate further. I also edited my response to get the client_id from the HTML instead of having to put it manually, and I put the login, pw & user-agent as variables now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Wim, I have written every login properly and doublechecked the credentials. Following failure now:
ERROR: Spider error processing <POST https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/password> (referer: https://account.booking.com/account/sign-in/login_name)
Traceback (most recent call last):

 line 85, in redirect
    redirect_uri = json.loads(response.body)['redirect_uri']
KeyError: 'redirect_uri'